# Is it possible to append lists of varying lengths as columns in an empty dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to create code that takes in a set of letters and outputs the different number of words you can make with them.

Here is my code so far:

```py
import itertools as itr
import requests
from PyDictionary import PyDictionary
import pandas as pd

x=list(input("enter letters given:"))
n=len(x)
dframe=pd.DataFrame()
dictionary=PyDictionary()
for i in range(2,n+1,1):
    combinations=list(itr.combinations_with_replacement(x,i))
    format_combinations=[]
    for letters in combinations:
        format_combinations.append(' '.join(letters))

    for idx,word in enumerate(format_combinations):
        word=word.replace(" ","")
        format_combinations[idx]=word
    dframe.loc[i]=format_combinations
```

Ignoring the last line of code, it works fine.

With this code I get the error:

```
ValueError: cannot set a frame with no defined column
```

So I added columns by changing my `dframe` to `dframe=pd.dataframe(columns=list(range(2,n+1,1)))`

I then got the following error:

```
ValueError: cannot set a row with mismatched columns
```

My question is, is it possible to create an empty dataframe then append my format_combination list to it as a column for each iteration.

Right now, I believe the error is coming from the fact that my `format_combination` list changes length during each iteration, but that's my guess. If someone could explain why I am getting this error and if there is any way to append lists as a column in an empty dataframe.

I am still new to pandas and dataframes and just want to know why I can't create a dataframe this way. So far, the only method I've used is to create a dictionary containing the data and use that to create my dataframe. I don't think I have come across an example where a dataframe was created iteratively before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not positive if this is the exact solution you were looking for, but when I am creating a pandas dataframe through iteration I like to use a numpy array as an intermediary. What you can do is:

1. append each iteration to a python list
2. convert that list to a numpy array and pad values (I used NaNs to pad)
3. convert your numpy array to a dataframe

```py
import itertools as itr
import requests
import pandas as pd
# import numpy
import numpy as np
x=list(input("enter letters given:"))
n=len(x)
# initialize a list
all_combs = []
for i in range(2,n+1,1):
       combinations=list(itr.combinations_with_replacement(x,i))
       format_combinations=[]
       for letters in combinations:
           format_combinations.append(' '.join(letters))
       for idx,word in enumerate(format_combinations):
           word=word.replace(" ","")
           format_combinations[idx]=word
       # append each iteration to the list
       all_combs.append(format_combinations)
# find the length of the longest iteration
pad = len(max(all_combs, key=len))
# create a numpy array from your list, pad with nans
arr = np.array([i + [np.nan]*(pad-len(i)) for i in all_combs])
# convert to dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame(arr)
# transpose to get one column per iteration
df = df.transpose()
```

EDIT:
Alternative method not using numpy

```py
import itertools as itr
import requests
import pandas as pd
x=list(input("enter letters given:"))
n=len(x)
# initialize empty dataframe
all_combs = pd.DataFrame()
for i in range(2,n+1,1):
       combinations=list(itr.combinations_with_replacement(x,i))
       format_combinations=[]
       for letters in combinations:
           format_combinations.append(' '.join(letters))
       for idx,word in enumerate(format_combinations):
           word=word.replace(" ","")
           format_combinations[idx]=word
       # create dataframe with one column named for this iteration
       df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict({i: format_combinations})
       # join with all_combs on the union of their indices
       all_combs = all_combs.join(df, how='outer')
```

Comment: This is what I was looking for, df just needs to be transposed as the end.

Comment: Gotcha, added an alternative method to get one column per iteration.

Answer (score 1):

.loc[ ] and .iloc[ ] will not allow you to *create* a new column.
Use plain square brackets to create a column:

```
dframe[i]=format_combinations
```

However then you will have the problem of creating columns with lengths different than the index.  You will have to either pad each column with NAs (NaNs), or I would suggest, instead of using a DataFrame, use a python dictionary, where the KEY is your 'i' and the VALUE is your list of format_combinations.  You can then iterate through the dictionary same as you would through the columns of the dataframe.  Alternatively, since you are basically keying by integer, instead of a dictionary, simply create a list of lists, where list item 'i' points to list 'format_combinations'

Here is your code using a dictionary, this works (although not yet checking dictionary for validity of word)

```
import itertools as itr
import requests
from PyDictionary import PyDictionary
import pandas as pd
x=list(input("enter letters given:"))
n=len(x)
results={}
dictionary=PyDictionary()
for i in range(2,n+1,1):
    combinations=list(itr.combinations_with_replacement(x,i))
    format_combinations=[]
    for letters in combinations:
        format_combinations.append(' '.join(letters))
    for idx,word in enumerate(format_combinations):
        word=word.replace(" ","")
        format_combinations[idx]=word
    results[i]=format_combinations
for res in results:
    print(results[res],'\n')
```

My understanding of a DataFrame is that the columns must all be the same length as the index --- it IS possible to have sparse data, or columns of 'effectively' different lengths, but (as I understand it) only by filling the missing values with NaN (or some other value to represent a missing value, such as a null or blank string).

Answer (score 1):

You need to assign a name to the  dataframe's columns first:

```
dframe = pd.DataFrame(columns=['Combinations'])
...
dframe.loc[i, 'Combinations'] = format_combinations
```

Comment: Nice!  This works too!   This creates a DataFrame with a *single* column where each row is the list of 'format_combinations' corresponding to 'i' ... essentially the single column is the dict that i mentioned in my answer.